# Rails - Devise - Limit user by domain name

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am using Devise for authentication on a web site with multiple domain names and I want to limit a user to log in by domain name. I save the allowed domain in my User model.

This would normally be easily handled by

```
def active_for_authentication?
    super and self.is_domain_allowed?
end
```

The challenge is that this function goes in the model and the model does not have access to the current domain `request.domain`, which is only available in the controller. I've looked at overriding `Devise::SessionsController`, but it seems like the only option there is to allow the login then immediately log the person out, which is not a clean solution.

Rails 4.2.6

Devise 3.5.10

Suggestions?